# jQuery ajax request using datatype jsonp still yields a 403 forbidden error

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery, http-status-code-403

I am spinning around this problem for a while and have looked up solutions online, following them hasn't really solved the problem. The context is a login page, where I must validate a user upon the supplied credentials using this strategy. So I use the typical jquery ajax function like this:

```
$.ajax(function(data){
url:"login/loginaction"
data: {email : email, password: password}
... // so on and so forth
});
```

Unfortunately this yields a '403 forbidden error' stating that this request is not authenticated. I prod around to find that this is a cross domain policy issue, primarily since the user is not authenticated hence the server spits out this issue. I realize that I can add an additional parameter in my ajax call to avoid this, that being :

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

However, it still gives me the same issue. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing here and how I can overcome this problem ?

Comment: It does not look cross domain to me, looks to be a relative path. Also changing the dataType to JSONP does not magically fix errors. 403 has to do with the security on the server.

Comment: so you think I need to specify the full path ? I am not sure how I can provide a full path because this is being done on a development site which is only exposed to the Intranet?  I mean I am testing it from the Intranet as well.

Comment: btw, the relative path point is a non-issue because I get a forbidden response from the actual URL, meaning the browser probably interprets the relative path to be that of the current URL and appends it

Comment: The problem hsa nothing to do with the JavaScript code. The problem is with the server. You are trying to access something on the server and the server says, *I do not think so*. Looks like you are trying to access a folder and not a actual page unless you have http rewrites going on.

Comment: not an actual folder, I am using the PHP Zend framework , so basically an action in a module which translates to, a function in a class, where each of these methods map to view templates, if that helps. Do you think I need to change something on my server ?

Comment: I re tagged it with zend-framework, maybe one of those folks can help you out.

Comment: If you are using ZF1 (probably the same with ZF2 but not sure), to access the LoginController -> loginAction() function, you will need to use the /login/login URL (not /loginaction).